# Deciding class variable name based on index

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My situation is like this:
I am calling a function which accepts an index and I need to return a variable name of an object.
My code is similar to below code:

```
  switch (boardIndex) {
      case 0:
        return this.returnPlatformStatus(this.loginObjArr[arrIndex].sys1);
      case 1:
        return this.returnPlatformStatus(this.loginObjArr[arrIndex].sys2);
      case 2:
        return this.returnPlatformStatus(this.loginObjArr[arrIndex].sys3);
      case 3:
        return this.returnPlatformStatus(this.loginObjArr[arrIndex].sys4);
      case 4:
        return this.returnPlatformStatus(this.loginObjArr[arrIndex].sys5);
      case 5:
        return this.returnPlatformStatus(this.loginObjArr[arrIndex].sys6);
```

And this one goes like index ranging in [0-20]. I am fed up of putting this switch case every time.
Is there any way we can construct variable name based on index?

Answer (score 2):

You could re-do your data structure to make it easier, making that object an array, or you can form the property names with simple string concatenation:

```
return this.returnPlatformStatus(this.loginJobArr[arrIndex]["sys" + (boardIndex + 1)]);
```

Object property names in JavaScript can always be created dynamically via a string expression. In this example, `"sys" + (boardIndex + 1)` will create strings as in the posted code, `"sys1"`, `"sys2"`, etc. The `[ ]` operator allows property access for objects just as it does for arrays; arrays *are* objects, after all.

Comment: Hi Pointy, it will be a huge change then... reconstructing the structure will not be feasible.

Comment: @Sarwan well then you can just do as I suggested in the answer: form the property names with simple string concatenation.